# Function object returning constant value

Tags: c++, lambda, anonymous-function

I want to call a function with the following signature:

```
void foreach(std::list<float>& floats, boost::function<float(float)> action);
```

This function iterates the list and modifies each element by executing `new_value = action(old_value)`. What is the shortest way to supply such an action function that returns always the same float value. I've never tried myself, but I'd guess C++11 lambdas will do the work:

```
foreach(floats, [](float){ return 3.14; });
```

What is the closest alternative in C++03, assuming I must call my function and cannot use `std::fill`? Is there a trick to avoid actually declaring a regular function?

Comment: Why not simply `std::fill(floats.begin(), floats.end(), 3.14)`?

Comment: See Boost.Phoenix, especially this [one](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/phoenix/doc/html/phoenix/starter_kit/values.html).

Comment: @dkrikun, looks like exactly what I need! Would you like to post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @FireAphis posted as answer, thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out Boost.Phoenix, it implements [values as nullary functions](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/phoenix/doc/html/phoenix/starter_kit/values.html).
Probably you will have to figure out how to use it with Boost.Function if you want to.

Here's an example of such a nullary function from the Phoenix tutorial:

```
template <typename F>
void print(F f)
{
    cout << f() << endl;
}

int
main()
{
    print(val(3));
    print(val("Hello World"));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use,

```
std::fill(floats.begin(), floats.end(), 3.14);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I really must call my specific function.

Answer (score 2):

> What is the closest alternative in C++03? Is there a trick to avoid actually declaring a regular function?

The closest trick in c++03 is to declare a function or a functor class :

```
float DoThing1( float )
{
  return 3.13;
}

struct DoThing2
{
  float operator()(float)
  {
    return 3.13;
  }
};
```

Comment: will there be any difference in using functor over a function in this case?

Comment: @Koushik the only difference is that for a functor, you have to create an object. For good compiler with proper optimization there wouldn't be difference

Comment: oh yeah compilers do it better. also a temporary also could do it right?

Comment: @Koushik What I meant is this : with proper optimization, both function and functor (with temporary) would result in the same thing

Comment: The functor is better than the function pointer. The code in the functor is written in a method of the class, which means it is implicitly `inline`, and the compiler will likely inline it into the `for_each` algorithm, since `for_each` would be templated by the type of this functor. On the other hand, with a function, it is not by default inlined. The `for_each` is only templated by the function pointer type, which does not contain the code of the function. A smart compiler may still figure out to inline it if you hard-code the function to use, but it is less certain.